# Increasing the coefficients of two numbers to sum to a targeted value

Tags: python, performance

I've naively tried to gradually increase two values so eventually, they sum to a targeted value.

Since this code runs many times and eventually for very large values, I don't know how to optimize so that it doesn't take more than 0.5 seconds.

```
def coefTargetSum(R, X, Y):
    coefResult = []
    for x in range(R):
        for y in range(R):
            if x * X + y * Y == R:
                coefResult.extend([x, y])
                return coefResult
    return -1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Rearrange the equation to find one variable from another.

  \$R = xX + yY\$
  \$xX = R - yY\$
  \$x = \frac{R - yY}{X}\$

  And so, if you don't want negative values of \$x\$, then you need to limit the range to \$\lfloor \frac{R}{X} \rfloor + 1\$.

  This also will return `float`s, which for the most part shouldn't make a difference as it's a subtype of `int`. However as we're limiting the results to integers then converting the number to an `int` could make sense.
- I also wouldn't return `-1`, but would instead use `None` or an empty list. This is as `-1` makes no logical sense.
- And rather than extending a list with another list, just return the wanted list. Better you could return a tuple.

This allows for:

```
def coefTargetSum(R, X, Y):
    for y in range(R // X + 1):
        x = (R - y*Y) / X
        if x % 1 == 0:
            return int(x), y
    return None
```

Comment: I'm confused, to me that looks like a test for an even number after an integer division in python2.

Comment: @stefan you're correct, I messed up the operator, it should have been a `%`, rather than a `&`. I also assume Python 3, or `from __future__ import division`.

Comment: Still you are returning float which may result in a TypeError.And you return negative x values as your loop runs up to R for no reason and you do not test for it (`coefTargetSum(24, 5, 11)`).

Comment: @stefan My code is purely for showing an alternate way to do something. It's rare to get a `TypeError`, but is adding `int(...)` that hard? So, the question doesn't say anything about results not being allowed to be negative.

Comment: If the task was not without negative numbers the search space would be infinite. You do limit the seach space to range(R), so you are accepting the non-negative-constraint. Just not fully.

Comment: @stefan So? My answer helped the OP, and looks to be good enough. If you have problems with my answer just put them in your answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69153/discussion-between-stefan-and-peilonrayz).

Answer (score 0):

There is some information missing. From your code I assume you work with integers.

- there is no need to iterate the whole range up to R
- you may test the second variable in a closed form

If indeed you want a single result only

```
def coefTargetSum(R, X, Y):
    for x in range(R // X + 1):
        y = (R - x*X) / Y
        if y.is_integer():
            return [x, int(y)]
    return None
```

however if you want a list of all results

```
def coefTargetSum(R, X, Y):
    coefResult = []
    for x in range(R // X + 1):
        y = (R - x*X) / Y
        if y.is_integer():
            coefResult.append((x, int(y)))
    return coefResult
```

In your case the testing of the second variable is quite cheap, it is a division only. however there are many cases where testing in a closed form is not possible (modulo operations, ...) or expensive (sqrt, ...). Then you have to try all combinations. But again you can do this more effective by avoiding to test previously known impossible combinations. you fill the sum completely with one type of elements (X) and depending on whether it is to big or not you continue by removing an X or adding a Y.

```
def coefTargetSum(R, X, Y):
    x = R // X
    y = 0
    coefResult = []
    while x >= 0:
        sum = x * X + y * Y
        if sum == R:
            coefResult.append((x, y))
        if sum >= R:
            x -= 1
        else:
            y += 1
    return coefResult
```